# About licence of fat free framwork

Tags: php, frameworks, free, fat

https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/development#FairLicensing

If the terms and conditions of this license are too restrictive for your use, 
alternative licensing is available for a very reasonable fee.
what is the name of alternative licence? how much the cost is?

Answer (score 0):

did you read this?

https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/development#Support

> Support
>
> Technical support is available at the official discussion forum:
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework.
>
> If you need live support, you can talk to the development team and
>   other members of the F3 community via Slack.